# Nginx Site Configuration for Development Environment

Tags: php, nginx, configuration, config

I'm currently trying to setup a generic, multi-project development environment in Vagrant for students of a web-development mentoring project. The idea is the domain `<project>.vagrant` maps to `~/code/<project>`
I thought I had enough experience with Nginx to solve this, but it turns out I don't.

Assuming that PHP-FPM is correctly setup, I need help with the `try_files`/routing for the site-configuration.
Whilst the homepage (`/`) works fine, any request to a non-static file (which should therefore be passed to PHP-FPM) results in either a *301 Moved Permanently* to the homepage, or downloads the contents of the PHP script instead of executing it.

> And yes I know listing so many index files is not ideal but the students will be dealing with multiple projects (phpMyAdmin, WordPress) and frameworks (Symfony, Silex, Laravel, etc).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

The contents of the single site-available configuration file so far is:

```
map $host $projectname {
    ~^(?P<project>.+)\.vagrant$ $project;
}

upstream phpfpm {
    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.vagrant;
    server_tokens off;
    root /home/vagrant/code/$projectname/web;
    index app_dev.php app.php index.php index.html;
    autoindex on;
    client_max_body_size 5M;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ / =404;
    }
    # Pass all PHP files onto PHP's Fast Process Manager server.
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|\?|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        # Specify the determined server-name, not the literal "*.vagrant".
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $projectname.vagrant;
        fastcgi_pass phpfpm;
    }
}
```